# Mysql query not inserting values

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to use the query below to insert a concatenated converted set of integers to string for use on a `datetime` field in my table.

TABLE

```
Field        Type
empID        int(11)
time_stamp   datetime
in_out       char(3)
am_pm        char(2)
```

QUERY

```vb
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO attendance VALUES(" & empID.Text & _
 "STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT("& empYear.Text & ",'-'," & empMonth.Text & ",'-'," & _
  empDay.Text & ",' '," & empHour.Text & ",':'," & empMin.Text & ",':'," & _
  empSec.Text & ",'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'out','pm')"
```

There is no problem with the connection and the values. I have tried to insert the values into a `test` column of string type and the output is this:

```
133201712311827
```

I am pretty sure it's with how I use these characters: `'' "" "," - :`. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Do yourself a favor - parameterize your SQL and you will not need this sadomazo of a date

Comment: do you have a clear/step by step/good read step by step on how to parameterize sql in vb.net?

Comment: There are plenty examples for query parameterization here on SO - see my answer

Comment: this `133201712311827` doesn't look right. According to your code should be `201712311827133`

Comment: `133201712311827`
`133`   = empID.Text
`2017` = empYear.Text
`1`       = empMonth.Text
`23`     = empDay.Text
`11`      = empHour.Text
`8`       = empMin.Text
`27`     = empSec.Text

Comment: Have you fixed your issue and what was the culprit?

Comment: i am unable to write the codes yet. hope you will be around once i did.

Comment: Look, My answer is **correct**. I went to sqlfiddle and replaced your text box values with hard-coded values and with corrections that I've told you to do (comma and parenthesis), the INSERT has worked and SELECT returned result. I will update the answer now

Comment: i understand and i know your answer for the _sql_ code is **correct**. my original code works as well in the cmd version of sql, my problem is with `VB.NET` as outlined in my `query` above.

Comment: The `"query above"` was only missing a comma and a closing parenthesis. Otherwise it is fine query, but unfortunately non-papameterized one. I don't think vb has anything to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem I see, here

```
& empID.Text & "STR_TO_DATE(. . .  .
```

you're missing comma after first value

```
& empID.Text & "***,*** STR_TO_DATE(. . . .
```

Second issue, I identified when I've replaced your text values with hard coded values - You are missing closing parenthesis for `str_to_date`. Here `,'%Y-%m-%d...` should be `), '%Y-%m-%d...`

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(1999,'-',01,'-',01,' ',10,':',25,':',30***)***,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

As you see- my replacement shows that you have no issues with concatenation, single quote and `:`. Theo only other variable here is quality of data in text boxes.

**Update**

This answer (above) is correct. Using sql fiddle I created schema and when replaced text box values with hard-coded ones - all worked. My suggestions to add comma and parenthesis hold true. Your claim about problems with single quotes are false.

```sql
create table xxx (empID int(11), time_stamp datetime, in_out char(3), am_pm  char(2));
INSERT INTO xxx VALUES(123,
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2017','-','1','-','23',' ','10',':','35',':','40'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),
    'out','pm');

commit;
Select * from xxx
```

> empID | time_stamp                           | in_out |   am_pm
>   
> 123      | January, 23 2017 10:35:40 | out      |   pm

**End Update**

On top of that, you could do it much better by parameterizing, which will look like something like this

```vb
command.CommandText = "insert into ... values (@1, @2, @3, @4)"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Convert.ToInt32(empID.Text))
dim date as new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(empYear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(empMonth.Text), . . . . )
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", date)
. . .  . . .
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Parameterizing will make it easy to work with dates and strings

Comment: i tried using your corrections but it did not insert any data :(

Comment: @oozmac My corrections are correct. if you parameterize you should have no issues. Unfortunately I am not big on MySql, so you need to check correct usage of mySql functions. For example, I don't know if this `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'` is correct. And it also would be helpful to know what error you're getting

Comment: that is correct.. as i have said the query works fine as is without `' ' " " :` these things

Comment: @oozmac Well, until you post error it will not be possible to judge - too many variables because data comes from text boxes. The things I told you - missing  comma, and missing parenthesis are correct. Once you get that right, I see no issues related to `' "  :` because those are just strings

Comment: i am doing what you have advised me and so far `empID.Text` got inserted to a `temporary table` just to try if it works, however, i'm not sure how to `str_to_date(concat())` the separate values of `'year, month, day, ' ' , hour, min, sec' ` to insert to my `datetime` datatype `time_stamp` column

Comment: @oozmac you had almost everything correct as far as concatenation goes. YOu only missing comma and closing parenthesis where I pointed. And unless you have wrong data in text boxes that should work. YOu not hearing me - what is the error?

Comment: @oozmac And also, I am not sure, it seem that `%H` should be `%h`. As I said, unless you parameterize you will have pains with dates and single quotes in strings...https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: i am parameterizing my code. i'll update you tomorrow on my progress. thank you

Comment: is this correct?
`str_insertAttendance = "insert into test values (@test)"`
`Dim empDate As New` `DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(empYear.Text),Convert.ToInt32(empMonth.Text),Convert.ToInt32(empDay.Text),Convert.ToInt32(empHour.Text),Convert.ToInt32(empMin.Text),Convert.ToInt32(empSec.Text))`
`sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", empDate)`